# Getting rid of a directory in the URL in Nginx

Tags: nginx

I have been searching around for this answer, but I can't find the one that fits my situation. So currently I have a URL that looks like: http://localhost/templates/verify but I want it to look like this: http://localhost/verify, but I'm not sure how I can my Nginx to do that.

Here's what my templates block to serve templates looks like

```
location /templates/ {
          try_files $uri.html $uri/ =404;
          autoindex on;

          }
```

How can I solve this problem using Nginx?

Comment: Can you clarify it please *but I want it to look like this*, do you intend to do a redirect instead?

Comment: @Anatoly I just want to get rid of the /templates in the URL.

Comment: Maybe use an [`alias`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) ?

Comment: nginx does not create your URLs, your web site does that.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have a path component in a URL, you shouldn't put it in the `location`.  If you want to serve content out of two separate directories and have them both show up at the same place in the URL path, you *can* use `try_files`, but you're in for a world of hurt if you do that, so don't.